# Redirect an external domain to another domain

Tags: redirect, ip, external, hosts

I want to redirect an external webpage (for example facebook.com) to another webpage (for example youtube.com). I tried to write the following lines in hosts file:
    173.252.120.6               64.233.165.136    #facebook ip to youtube ip
But it doesn't work.
What's the problem, how could I solve it, if possible without a special software?

Answer (score 0):

That line in your hosts file does not look correct. The syntax for the hosts file should be as follows, replacing the IP_Address with the actual number :

> 127.0.0.1       localhost
>
> IP_Address      youtube.com